# $\mathrm{arctanh} (x+y) = ?$

Tags: inverse-function, hyperbolic-functions

Is there a formula for expanding

$$\mathrm{arctanh} (x+y)?$$

I have never seen or could find one.

Comment: as you wrote in the title : $\text{arctanh}(x+y)= ?$ ;-)

Comment: Surely there must exist a formula for expanding this?

Comment: $2\tanh^{-1}(x+y)=\ln(1+x+y)-\ln(1-x-y)$. But $1\pm(x+y)$ doesn't have a nice factorisation, so there'e no obvious way to simplify its logarithm.

Comment: Probably not in terms of $\tanh^{-1}(x)$ and $\tanh^{-1}(y).$